# Ruby returning imaginary number

Tags: ruby

Getting a confusing result when doing an exponential equation in ruby:

```rb
shifted_x = -97.0
exponent = 1.5

shifted_x**exponent
# Result: (0.0-955.3392067742221i)


-97.0**1.5
# Result: -955.3392067742221
```

My expectation is that the results would be the same but they are not. What changes when using the variable that causes ruby to return an imaginary (or complex) number?

Comment: Because the first calculation is [`(-97)^1.5`](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28-97%29%5E1.5), but the second is [`-(97^1.5)`](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-%2897%5E1.5%29). So you get different answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Operator precedence.

`-97.0**1.5` is equivalent to `-(97.0**1.5)`

`shifted_x**exponent` is, of course, equivalent to `(-97.0)**1.5`

---

Note that `(-97.0)**1.5` is equivalent to `sqrt((-97)^3)` and taking the root of a negative real number gives you a complex number.